# Are these ponderosa pines?

Tags: identification, pines

These hundreds of these pine trees are planted on either side of the road in a row.

[image]

The location is inland (not coastal) San Diego, particularly in location that's very windy (lots of prairies and mountains to gust up the wind) and hot.

The needles are about 4-6 inches long. When mature the needles are a shade of light to dark green. But the new seedlings on the ground usually put out bluish green needles.

My best guess is that they are ponderosa based on the straight trunks, long branches, and long needles. Does anyone have a better guess?

What other information is required for me to identify these trees?

UPDATE:
The needles are in bunches of 3.

Please see photo of the cone. It is about 6 inches tall and 4 inches wide.
[image]

Comment: An important marker is " how many needles in a bundle" . also cone description . Because they are planted almost anything is possible. The picture looks rather like our Loblolly  ( unlikely in that location).

Comment: @blacksmith37 I've updated the post. Does this help? Please let me know if I should collect some other info.

Comment: Probably Ponderosa Pine ; I seen on the internet there are 5 recognized subspecies which have small differences.